# Stop Hover Menu Closing when User Moves Out of Section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, stoppropagation

I have a side menu that opens when the user hovers over it. In one section when the user clicks on a menu item a popover opens next to it.

[image]

But when you move onto the popover to select something from the dropdown menu the hover menu closes and leaves the popover. I tried using `stopPropagation()`, but the menu still closes.

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

```
<li class="active treeview menu-open" id="testExecution">
  <!-- sidebar menu item 1: Test Execution -->
  <a>
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i> <span>Test Execution</span>
    <span class="pull-right-container">
      <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
    </span>
  </a>
  <ul class="treeview-menu">
    <!-- sidebar submenu -->
    <li class="active treeview menu-open" id="partnersTree" onclick="closePopovers()">
      <a>
        <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> <span>Partners</span>
        <span class="pull-right-container">
          <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
        </span>
      </a>
      <ul class="treeview-menu">
        <li class="active" id='tab1'><a><i class="fa fa-circle"></i> tab1</a></li>
        <li id='tab2'><a><i class="fa fa-circle"></i>tab2</a></li>
        <li id='tab3'><a><i class="fa fa-circle"></i> tab3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="treeview" id="historySettings">
      <a>
        <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> <span>History Settings</span>
        <span class="pull-right-container">
          <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
        </span>
      </a>
      <ul class="treeview-menu">
        <li><a id="versionHistory" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right">
          <i class="fa fa-gear"></i> <span>Version History</span>
          <span class="pull-right-container">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-right pull-right"></i>
          </span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <div class='_content' id='versionHistoryPicker' style='width:250px'>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Select Version:</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="versionDropdown" style="background-color:#ffffff; color:#777777" >
              <option selected="selected" disabled="true"> Please Select Version </option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block" onclick="drawHistoryCharts()">Submit</button>
        </div>
        <li><a id="dateHistory" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right">
          <i class="fa fa-gear"></i> <span>Date History</span>
          <span class="pull-right-container">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-right pull-right"></i>
          </span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <div class='_content' id='dateHistoryPicker' style='width:250px'>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Date range:</label>
            <div class="input-group">
              <div class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
              </div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="reservation">
            </div>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block" onclick="dateHistoryChart()">Submit</button>
        </div>
        <li><a onclick="onLoad()">
          <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> <span>RESET PAGE</span>
          <span class="pull-right-container">
          </span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

```
$("#testExecution").mouseout(
  function(e) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
```

Comment: Do you have more css and markup that goes with that ?

Comment: The simplest way might be to use an invisible element to close the gap.